# Embedding a resource with more than one period in the filename

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to include some Javascript files in a class library as an embedded resource. For files without periods in the filename, this works well. However, it seems that when there are periods in the filename, the resource doesn't get embedded without any notification; I can't programmatically access the resource (using `GetManifestResourceStream`), nor see the resource name (using `GetManifestResourceNames`), nor see the resource using ILDASM.

It didn't work when set through the UI, nor when I set the logical name in the project file as follows:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Scripts\gridmvc.lang.he.js">
  <LogicalName>$(RootNamespace).gridmvc-lang-he.js</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

I can rename the file, but I would prefer to keep the file intact.

(I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, and the class library is in VB.NET, but I am almost certain the precise version/language don't make a difference.)

Comment: Pretty likely that you use the wrong resource name to find it back.  Using the Resource Designer is always best.  Use ildasm.exe to see the resource names.  Double-click the manifest, you see the .mresource statements.

Comment: @HansPassant Shouldn't I see it using `GetManifestResourceNames`? It returns 5 resource names and I don't see anything remotely resembling this file.

Comment: You assume your code doesn't have a bug and that the resource was embedded correctly.  I know that ildasm.exe doesn't have a bug and can properly show embedded resources.  It is therefore the correct tool to use to start diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Using ildasm.exe, I see all the other resources, but not this one.

Comment: You are supposed to put that info your question.  Use the Resource Designer to fall in the pit of success.  Project > Properties > Resources tab.  Click the arrow on the Add Resources button > Add Existing File.  Use My.Resources.SomeName in your code.